# Возможно ли добавить что-то дополнительно в HSSFCell?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Можно ли, и есть ли да, то как добавить в определённый `specialArrayList` `case 3:` дополнительно что-то?
На примере      `System.out.println("\"" + cell + "\"");`
Иными словами мне нужно что-бы в `specialArrayList` хранились данные с "", которых нет в загружаемом мною Excel файле.

```
    ArrayList<String> specialArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

....

```
for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
    int no = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    HSSFRow rov = sheet.getRow(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        HSSFCell cell = rov.getCell(i, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                firstArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 1:
                secondArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 2:
                thirdArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            case 3:
                specialArrayList.add(formatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё было просто оказывается. Так радует когда сам доходишь до ответа :)

```
                   case 7:
                        invoice_nr.add("\"" + formatter.formatCellValue(cell) + "\"");
                        break;
```